# configure alerts if a new AD group is created which has the keywords "Keyword2" and "Keyword2" using logic app

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps

Need an approach to configure alerts (email) when a new AD group is created which the keywords "Keyword2" and "Keyword2". Looking for a logic app approach and any suggestions are appreciated.

Tried below approach but did not worked:

Trigger: When an HTTP request is received

Action: Parse JSON

Content: Body of the incoming HTTP request
Schema: Use the JSON schema of the incoming Azure AD group creation event
Condition: @contains(body('Parse_JSON')?['displayName'], 'Key1-Key2')

Action: Send an email (Email connector) or Send a message (Teams connector)

Comment: “Didn’t work” why? Also, what’s triggering that http request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could get this done using the below expression.

```
"expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "contains": [
                                        "@items('For_each')?['displayName']",
                                        "Key1-Key2"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
```

Here is the flow of my logic app

[image]

[image]

Results:

[image]

Below is the complete code view of my logic app.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "body": {
                                        "Body": "<p>The group @{items('For_each')?['displayName']} has created at @{items('For_each')?['createdDateTime']}. Below are the complete details <br>\n<br>\n------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>\n<br>\n@{body('Parse_JSON')}</p>",
                                        "Importance": "Normal",
                                        "Subject": "Alert",
                                        "To": "<EMAIL ADDRESS>"
                                    },
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['outlook']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "post",
                                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "contains": [
                                        "@items('For_each')?['displayName']",
                                        "Key1-Key2"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "@@odata.context": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "value": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "classification": {},
                                        "createdDateTime": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "creationOptions": {
                                            "type": "array"
                                        },
                                        "deletedDateTime": {},
                                        "description": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "displayName": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "expirationDateTime": {},
                                        "groupTypes": {
                                            "type": "array"
                                        },
                                        "id": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "isAssignableToRole": {},
                                        "mail": {},
                                        "mailEnabled": {
                                            "type": "boolean"
                                        },
                                        "mailNickname": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "membershipRule": {},
                                        "membershipRuleProcessingState": {},
                                        "onPremisesDomainName": {},
                                        "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": {},
                                        "onPremisesNetBiosName": {},
                                        "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": {
                                            "type": "array"
                                        },
                                        "onPremisesSamAccountName": {},
                                        "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": {},
                                        "onPremisesSyncEnabled": {},
                                        "preferredDataLocation": {},
                                        "preferredLanguage": {},
                                        "proxyAddresses": {
                                            "type": "array"
                                        },
                                        "renewedDateTime": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "resourceBehaviorOptions": {
                                            "type": "array"
                                        },
                                        "resourceProvisioningOptions": {
                                            "type": "array"
                                        },
                                        "securityEnabled": {
                                            "type": "boolean"
                                        },
                                        "securityIdentifier": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "theme": {},
                                        "visibility": {}
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "id",
                                        "deletedDateTime",
                                        "classification",
                                        "createdDateTime",
                                        "creationOptions",
                                        "description",
                                        "displayName",
                                        "expirationDateTime",
                                        "groupTypes",
                                        "isAssignableToRole",
                                        "mail",
                                        "mailEnabled",
                                        "mailNickname",
                                        "membershipRule",
                                        "membershipRuleProcessingState",
                                        "onPremisesDomainName",
                                        "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime",
                                        "onPremisesNetBiosName",
                                        "onPremisesSamAccountName",
                                        "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier",
                                        "onPremisesSyncEnabled",
                                        "preferredDataLocation",
                                        "preferredLanguage",
                                        "proxyAddresses",
                                        "renewedDateTime",
                                        "resourceBehaviorOptions",
                                        "resourceProvisioningOptions",
                                        "securityEnabled",
                                        "securityIdentifier",
                                        "theme",
                                        "visibility",
                                        "onPremisesProvisioningErrors"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "HTTP": {
                "conditions": [],
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "inputs": {
                    "headers": {
                        "Authorization": "Bearer <BEARER_TOKEN>"
                    },
                    "method": "GET",
                    "uri": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "type": "Http"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "outlook": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/outlook",
                    "connectionName": "outlook",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/outlook"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```